# book class: suppress page number on even blank page

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, document-classes

Using a simple `\documentclass{book}`, all new chapters start on odd pages. Now if the previous chapter also ends on an odd page, the next even page will be blank but nevertheless gets page number printed underneath. Is it possible suppress this page number on empty even pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the preamble write:

`\usepackage{emptypage}`

and all works as you like.